# How to set multiple vertical axes in dymola during plotting the results?

Tags: modelica, dymola

After finishing the simulation, how could I set multiple vertical axes in dymola during plotting the results?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, on the left, you can select a variable, then below that you can change the vertical axis from "Left" to "Right". Only makes sense if you have two variables plotted in the same plot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can have that in a single plot window. You can make multiple windows as described in [Dymola Basics](https://www.claytex.com/blog/dymola-basics-6-plotting-features/), but i never found any option of having multiple y-axis in a single plot.

Answer (score 8):

Select a variable. Change ”vertical axis”. You can have one axis left and one right.

[image]