# Set the Y-axis in the right side in Modelica OMEdit plot

Tags: simulation, modelica, dymola

For specific reasons i want to change the Y-axis location from left to right.
so if anyone can help me with the way.
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590637/how-to-set-multiple-vertical-axes-in-dymola-during-plotting-the-results shows the dymola solution. But OMEdit in my knowledge doesn't have that feature. I can be wrong too!

Answer (score 0):

I search for a long time to set the Y-axis in the right side but OpenModelica does not have that feature.

Comment: If you are comfortable with matplotlib then please see this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369888/matplotlib-y-axis-label-on-right-side